# Populating a @Html.DropDownListFor() from database that can submit values to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to develop a ASP.net mvc application using entity framework 6. 
There are 2 entities as `Driver` & `DriverType`. When adding a new driver to the database, User should be able to select the Driver Type from a DropDownList.
When submitting the form, The ID of the selected DriverType should be added to the `DriverTypeID` (Foreign Key) column in the `Driver` Table.

My Question is how to fetch all the DriverTypes to the DropDownList when loading the page & How to pass the ID of the selected DriverType to the `Driver` table?

My Model classes as follows.

Driver Class

```
    public partial class Driver
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Driver()
    {
        this.trip_tab = new HashSet<Trip>();

    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string DriverTypeID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual DriverType drivertype_tab { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Trip> trip_tab { get; set; }
}
```

Driver Type Class

```
    public partial class DriverType
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public DriverType()
    {
        this.driver_tab = new HashSet<Driver>();
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Driver> driver_tab { get; set; }
}
```

}

I'm using database first approach.

Comment: The relevant code needs to be in the question. Not images of it.

Comment: Those are paste bin links. Not images. Anyway I'll add code to the question.

Comment: Start by using a view model that will contain a property `int SelectedDriver` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DriverList` (and populate `DriverList` using `db.DriverTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){ Value = x.ID, Text = x.Type });` Then refer the code in [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: you also need to add some controler and view code here

Answer (score 0):

you can create a selectList in your action and pass this selectList to a ViewBag and then access this ViewBag in your view. you should do this in your action first:

```
var allDriverTypes=_driverTypeService.GetAll();
ViewBag.DriverTypes=new SelectList(allDriverTypes,"ID","Title");
```

now in view you should do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DriverTypeID,(SelectList)ViewBag.DriverTypes)
```

after do this when your form submit and come back to post controller you can see driverTypeId that user choose bind to your model.

note: when you create a selectList you have a list that contain IDs and Titles that you want to show in your dropdown.